# Replace backslash path for forward slash path with sed in loop

Tags: bash, sed, tcsh

I want to replace windows server paths (\\100.100.0.0\aaa\bbb\ccc\) with linux paths /foo/bar/ on all occurrences inside all .txt files in a folder (/xxx/yyy/zzz/).

For that I made a loop that does not seem to work either on bash or tcsh (using foreach).

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES="/xxx/yyy/zzz/*.txt"
for f in $FILES
do
        sed -i 's+\\100.100.0.0\aaa\bbb\ccc\+/foo/bar/+g' $f
done
```

The error I get is the following:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 133: unterminated `s' command
```

I am guessing the issue must be in how sed handles these tricky characters but I cannot identify it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\` is an escaping operator in regexp syntax (and many other things), so needs to be escaped itself, along with `.` which is also special there. Here, the `\` in front of `+` caused the `+` not to be taken as the delimiter in `s+pattern+replacement+flag`.

You also don't need the loop nor bash.

```
#! /bin/sh -
sed -i 's|\\\\100\.100\.0\.0\\aaa\\bbb\\ccc\\|/foo/bar/|g' /xxx/yyy/zzz/*.txt
```

If you wanted to use bash and a variable, you'd rather use an array:

```
#! /bin/bash -
shopt -s nullglob
files=( /xxx/yyy/zzz/*.txt )
if (( ${#files[@]} > 0 )); then
  sed -i -- 's|\\\\100\.100\.0\.0\\aaa\\bbb\\ccc\\|/foo/bar/|g' "${files[@]}"
fi
```

Though if you're going to use a shell other than `sh`, `bash` is a relatively poor choice (not as poor as (t)csh of course which shouldn't be used in this century). Several shells including zsh, ksh93 or fish would make it easier and cleaner.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you very much, I will familiarize myself with other shells.